# Regex Data annotation no dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core

to consumindo uma api externa e uma das propriedades tem hífen: position-number.

Como consigo colocar uma anotação pra que eu consiga receber esse valor? Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]$",
ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
public object position-number;

Comment: Tente essa expressão regular aqui: ^[a-zA-Z\d-]+$

Comment: O seu problema é fazer o parse desse parâmetro ou validar em sua model?

Answer (score 0):

Se a estrutura de dados que está recebendo ou enviando possui hífen na chave (e não no valor), então você precisa mapear pro (de)serializer.

Se for JSON:

```
[JsonProperty("position-number")]
public string PositionNumber { get; set; }
```

Se for XML:

```
[DataMember(Name = "position-number")]
public string PositionNumber { get; set; }
```